# VB.Net guess user's number from 1 to 1000

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a guessing game that guesses the user's number from 1 to 1000. The user inputs if the number is higher or lower than the computer's guess. Based on the user's input, the computer each time halves the amount of the guess (e.g. first guess is 500, second is 250, third 125, etc, etc)

However I have encountered a problem when I am running this program. After pressing 'higher' or 'lower' for a few times, I am unable to change the output any further. I suppose this is to do with `amount = amount / 2` reaching a limit where it can barely be added or subtracted into `intGuess`. I have tried doing `amount = (amount / 2) + 1,` but that sometimes doesn't allow me to get to a number.
How would I counteract this problem?

Here is my code:

```
Dim intGuess As Integer = 500
Dim amount As Integer = 500
Dim count As Integer = 0


    Private Sub btnLower_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLower.Click
        amount = amount / 2
        intGuess = intGuess - amount
        lblGuess.Text = $"Is your number {intGuess} ?"
        count = count + 1
    End Sub

 
    Private Sub btnHigher_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnHigher.Click
        amount = amount / 2
        intGuess = intGuess + amount
        lblGuess.Text = $"Is your number {intGuess} ?"
        count = count + 1
    End Sub
```

Just thought I should add this, but the first guess is 500.

Comment: You don't need to guess. You have a debugger at your disposal so you can debug your code and see exactly what's happening the whole time.

Comment: One of the biggest mistakes beginners make is trying to go from an idea, straight to code, without actually knowing what that code has to do. Code is just an implementation of logic so you should ALWAYS work out the logic first and then write code to specifically implement that logic. In this case, once you have debugged your code and seen where the logic error is, you can work out how you would handle the situation if you were doing it manually, then write code to implement that logic. If you haven't already solved the logic problem, you don't actually have a programming problem yet.

Comment: I have figured out that I need a way so that amount does not keep halving. I just do not know how I would implement that logic into my program. Would using an if statement to check if amount is less than 0.5 work? @user18387401

Comment: Did you, under a different username, post this same question a week or two ago? I've definitely heard this before recently...

Comment: Yeh! Found it...  [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72315230/vb-net-users-number-guessing-game

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VB.Net user's number guessing game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72315230/vb-net-users-number-guessing-game)

Comment: @video.baba, yes that is me, but i am having a different problem this time!

Answer (score 0):

I play this game verbally with my young son. I tell him to guess a number from 1 to 1000 and guarantee I can guess it in 10 or fewer guesses. It is a simple binary search. You can research binary search to come up with an algorithm. It's pretty simple and I've split it up into buttons like you have. Here is my form

[image]

The code to make it work is

```vb
Private guess As Integer
Private max As Integer
Private min As Integer
Private Sub StartButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartButton.Click
    If Integer.TryParse(MaxTextBox.Text, max) AndAlso
            Integer.TryParse(MinTextBox.Text, min) AndAlso
            max > min Then
        makeGuess()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Error in max or min, cannot continue! Fix max and min and try again.")
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub HigherButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HigherButton.Click
    min = guess
    makeGuess()
End Sub
Private Sub LowerButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LowerButton.Click
    max = guess
    makeGuess()
End Sub
Private Sub JustRightButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles JustRightButton.Click
    MessageBox.Show($"That's right, I found your number, it is {guess}!")
End Sub
Private Sub makeGuess()
    guess = CInt((max - min) / 2 + min)
    GuessLabel.Text = guess.ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Could you set a value to `min` and `max` and just put that as your first guess instead? (sorry if stupid question)

Comment: Of course, just set them and change the line `If Integer.TryParse(MaxTextBox.Text, max) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(MinTextBox.Text, min) AndAlso max > min Then`

Comment: Note, you didn't have a value for `max` in your code. If the number is higher, how high should your next guess be? The upper limit was unbounded so I think that is what you were missing.

Comment: I understand now! I thought it would work without adding `max` or `min`, but apparently that was not the case